How to power and dim 3S10P LEDs from a USB-C using MT3608 and AL8860 for flicker-free operation?
I'm a electrical newbie. I’m working on a project where I need to power and dim a set of LEDs from a USB-C power bank (5 V, 3 A max). My LED configuration is 3 LEDs in series per string (3S) and 10 such strings in parallel (10P), making a total of 30 LEDs. Each LED (GWJTLMS3.GM) has a forward voltage of about 2.95 V and runs at 60 mA. I’m including an 18 Ω resistor in each string for current balancing.
My proposed solution is:

Power Source: USB-C 5 V/3 A power bank as the input without PD.

Voltage Boost: Use an MT3608 boost converter to step up from 5 V to around 12–14 V.

LED Driver & Dimming: Use an AL8860 LED driver for constant current and analog dimming. To achieve flicker-free
operation (even under slow-motion video), I plan to use analog
dimming rather than low-frequency PWM. I’ll design a jumper on the
PCB to select between a standard analog potentiometer or a digital
potentiometer for controlling the LED driver’s Ctrl pin, with the
analog pot as the default.


Here is my concerns & questions:

AL8860 Powering LEDs in Series & Parallel: The examples given out on the datasheet and from SparkFun are all about powering series of high-power LEDs (350 mA). Would it make sense if I configure this to power the same ic of 3S10P medium-power white LEDs (60 mA)? Would there be a significant issue for thermal runway?

PCB Design: When designing MT3608 with AL8860 on the same PCB board, could they be on the same shared ground? Will there be any EMI I should consider? If so, how can I mitigate this?

Alternative Approaches: Are there simpler or more efficient LED drivers or topologies for running multiple LED strings with smooth analog dimming directly from a 5 V source?


Any insights or recommendations for ensuring stable, flicker-free dimming and good efficiency would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

why not 4S? ...

Hi @jsotola Thanks for the comment. Based on my understanding, the reason that I'm using 3S is because AL8860 datasheet graphs shows that when Vin is 14V I can get tested 9.9V at 650mA out of it with the current sense resistor and inductor set at Rs=0.15Ω, L=47μH. Having a larger difference between Vin and expected voltage helps increase the frequency to around 250Khz. That is my reason behind the 3S10P setup. Is there something I might be missing? Thanks!
